# Recursively return a tuple of numbers 0 to n in python

Tags: python, recursion, tuples

So what I'm trying to do is basically make a recursive function that returns a tuple of numbers from 0 to a given number n that does not use range(), loops or lists. The problem reads as this:

"Define a recursive function called rec_range() that takes a natural number n and returns a tuple of numbers starting with 0 and ending before n. So rec_range(5) returns (0,1,2,3,4) and rec_range(1) returns (0,)."

The problem is that I have no idea how to make a function that returns a tuple. I know how to get a factorial of a number n using recursion, but we never went over how to return multiple numbers in a tuple.

The only thing I have right now is this:

```
def rec_range(n):
    """Takes a natural number n and returns a tuple of numbers starting with 0 and ending before n.

    Natural Number -> tuple"""
    if n == 0
        return (,)
    elif n == 1:
        return (0,)
    else:
        ???
```

Sorry if the answer to this is actually really obvious I'm very new to programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to append tuples together, so use `+` and recurse over your function lowering the value by 1 . In addition, just `return` (or `return None`) for `n == 0`. Really the `n == 0` call is unnecessary and your code could be more idiomatic, but I'll leave that to you.

```
def rec_range(n):
    """Takes a natural number n and returns a tuple of numbers starting with 0 and ending before n.

    Natural Number -> tuple"""
    if n == 0:
        return 
    elif n == 1:
        return (0,)
    else:
        return rec_range(n-1) + (n-1,)
```

**Outputs:**

```
>>>rec_range(4)
(0, 1, 2, 3)
```